# Integer validation with exact 10 digits in migrations

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, database-migration

Trying write to phone number validation at database level, that will take exact 10 numeric digits.

Tried

```
t.integer :phone, null: false
t.integer :phone, null: false, size: 10
t.integer :phone, null : false, limit: 5
```

But it didn't work.

My findings

```
:limit      Numeric Type    Column Size     Max value
1           tinyint         1 byte          127
2           smallint        2 bytes         32767
3           mediumint       3 bytes         8388607
nil, 4, 11  int(11)         4 bytes         2147483647
5..8        bigint          8 bytes         9223372036854775807
```

When i did not pass limit, it commits `123` and rejects to commit `9999999999`. due to no min value and max value`(2147483647)` limitations.

Need to commit exact 10 digits to database nor less neither more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`size` or `limit` options will not work. For example limit = 9, but we can still save a value length = 8, that makes sense.

How about just using active record validation, it is super easy:

```
validates_length_of :phone, is: 9
```

For data consistency, we can add a migration with constraint

```
class AddMyConstraint < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute "ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT check_phone_length CHECK (phone >= 1000000000 AND phone <= 999999999 )"
  end

  def down
    execute "ALTER TABLE table_name DROP CONSTRAINT check_phone_length"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Hieu, but your solution is related to model validation. If i do `User.new(phone: 1234567890123).save(validate: false)` it fails to validate, so i need to restrict as it on database level also.